# Sperner's lemma and dynamical systems

Tags: combinatorics, dynamical-systems

My dynamical systems professor, gave Sperner's lemma and some other combinatoric lemmas before Brouwer's fixed point theorem and before Dynamical Systems module. Is it there any relation between these themes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a proof of Brouwer that uses Sperner.

Comment: See here in Fox's notes: http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-lecture03.pdf